# Can't run Traefik load balancer without hostPort

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

I am trying to setup traefik loadbalancer in the google cloud engine.
My configuration:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
  namespace: default
  labels:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: traefik-ingress-lb
        name: traefik-ingress-lb
      annotations:
         traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/frontend-entry-points: http,https
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      serviceAccountName: traefik-ingress-controller
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: traefik-config
      containers:
      - image: traefik
        name: traefik-ingress-lb
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/config"
            name: "config"
        ports:
        - name: admin
          containerPort: 8080
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
          #hostPort: 80
        - name: https
          containerPort: 443
        args:
        - --api
        - --kubernetes
        - --logLevel=DEBUG
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
    - name: admin
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
```

Traefik ui:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-ui
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-ui
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: traefik-web-ui
          servicePort: 8080
```

Unfortunately this does not work. The service and pods are running and there are no errors. But when I try to connect it's infinitely loading (funnily a ping works).
If I adjust my configuration to use hostPort it is working for one pod. The other pod will never be created, because the hostPort is already used by the first pod (error: pod fails to fit host port).

So how can I fix this to use multiple pods without using a demonset?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to connect it to a Google Cloud Load balancer you'll need a host port from your VM. What happens is that Kubernetes probably gives it a random port on the host but your Google Cloud Load Balancer is pointing to 80. You might want to try to assign `targetPort` on your service the name of the backend port in your service. That would be `http` or `https` or `admin` in your case I believe.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: https
    - name: admin
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: admin
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, I updated my post. If I am using hostPort it's no problem to open the dashboard or any other service. But when using the provided code in my question, I can't even connect to the site. It's infinitely loading. Even if I add the targetPort as you provided it does not work. Any other thoughts?

Comment: why do you not want to use hostPort?

Comment: Because I wanted have multiple pods of the load balancer. If I do it with hostport, only one pod can be created (reason: see in my question).

Comment: Changed the answer, added another suggestion

Comment: Unfortunately your updated answer is the same as my ^^ so I already tried that and in my opinion it should work, but for some reason it doesn't.